# Unknown Top Bar and Bottom Bar in Debian 10

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, xfce, desktop-environment

I have been using Debian 10 for many weeks and last night I installed Xfce-4  just to try it out, and then I uninstalled it.
But when I uninstalled, and got my Gnome Desktop back, I got new, unnknown top and bottom panels (as shown in the picture) which I don't like. I want to remove them. How can I do that?

[image: Screenshot of the desktop]

Comment: That still looks like xfce.

Comment: Yah!! That's the whole case.How can I fix it?